# How to create 3d models to use with sceneform?

Tags: android-studio, 3d, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I want to create an AR app in android studio using sceneform which displays different pair of glasses on users faces.My question is how do i create these models?Also,how will the positioning of the model on the face work?

Answer (score 3):

Creation of 3D models is done with software tools such as [Blender](https://www.blender.org/),
[Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [3DS Max](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview) etc.

You can either find a professional 3D artist or find assets on the web, the recommended site for developers to use is [Poly](https://poly.google.com/) where you can download these formats:

**Edit: as usual Google is also shutting down the poly website so you will have to find another 3D model website**

1. glTF (Recommended since it packages everything into one)
2. obj
3. fbx

For the positioning of the glasses onto the face, check out [Augmented faces](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/augmented-faces) which allows your app to automatically identify different regions of a detected face

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation

> Sceneform supports 3D assets in the following formats: * OBJ * glTF (animations not supported) * FBX, with or without animations. - https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/import-assets

For face tracking you will need to configure the ARCore session to detect/track faces

```
override fun getSessionConfiguration(session: Session): Config {
 val config = Config(session)
 config.augmentedFaceMode = Config.AugmentedFaceMode.MESH3D
 return config
}
```

For more details you can check out this tutorial from Captech: https://captechconsulting.com/blogs/getting-started-with-augmented-faces-with-arcore

***Note***: I am not affiliated with Captech, IMO they did a good job at explaining all the elements of building a face tracking app with ARCore.